# Using fopen to create a file in PHP has permission denied

Tags: php, file, file-permissions

I want to create a file on the fly and write some JSON to it.  I have the JSON and that's fine.  But something is amiss when I try to create the file.  It seems like it might be an issue of permissions or file owner, but I'm unsure how to fix it.  Here is my code:

```
$strFile = PUBLIC_PATH . '/javascript/members.json';
if (!file_exists($strFile)) {
    chmod(PUBLIC_PATH . '/javascript', 0755);  // operation not permitted error
    fopen($strFile, 'w');
    chmod($strFile, 0755);
    chown($strFile, 'www');
}
file_put_contents($strFile, $arrMembers);
```

I feel like I missing something really obvious here.

Comment: I believe I have to set the owner to www.  The current owner is my computer.

Comment: If the webserver user doesn't have permissions to edit the file / directory in the first place, it can't change the permissions with chmod.  You'll have to do that outside of the PHP script.

Comment: chown must be run first, but only the owner or su/root can modify the owner and privs.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user that PHP runs under have "X" permission on every directory of the file path.
It will need it to access the file

If your file is: /path/to/test-in.txt
You should have X permission on:

```
/path
/path/to
```

and read permission on /path/to/test-in.txt or through CPanel/ftp provide the write access to the file

Comment: I think that's the problem, but how do I do that with PHP?

Comment: Through programming lot of coding required to used ftp or CPanel to change the permission

Comment: I tried chmod'ing the directory 'javascript' and I'm getting operation not permitted.

Comment: use ftp client to do this thing